# I am getting a timeout error 408 when trying to load a third-party template onto my AWS-hosted wordpress site. How do I fix this?

Tags: amazon-web-services, web

I'm using AWS to host my wordpress site. I have purchased Semplice 4 which is an appearance/theme that I need to manually load onto wordpress. However, every time I try and load it, I get a HTTP timeout 408 error code.

I assume this is something to do with the way my AWS, but due to my inexperience am unable to troubleshoot.

Apologies in advance for my beginner-level knowledge, but I'll try and explain what I have done via setup as best as possible.

I used EC2, then created an instance and an elastic IP (which I connected to the domain name I've purchased).

Then I was using Route 53 to create a hosted zone and that record set has my domain name attached to it as a type 'A' (as well as the stock NS and SOA). I then took all the values from the NS record set and input them to my domain provider so it would link to my domain name.

I then loaded wordpress using the WordPress Certified by Bitnami option, and then I have to upload this zip file in order to use the third party software and it's not working - I get the 408 error.

Request Timeout
Server timeout waiting for the HTTP request from the client.

Is what I see, and it should just initialise the template.

Answer (score 0):

You must be sure that EC2 instance's security group has inbound traffic rule for HTTP port 80. Usually, timeout response is caused because the client cann't to access the application running in EC2 instance launched with default rules in security groups.

Comment: Thanks for the response - My inbound rules indicate a rule for HTTP port 80, the source is 0.0.0.0/0

Does that source need to change to my IP perhaps?

It looks like that security group was set up automatically when I used the Wordpress Certified By Bitnami option

Comment: You don't need change the source because it indicates that can to access from anywhere. The problem is another.

Comment: Can you access to the application from public IP or Elastic IP directly?

Comment: I'm almost certain I set it up using an elastic IP. But I don't know - I seem to be able to access wordpress using the IP address followed by /wp-admin